# Add variable to show any text in wxpython frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

So, I'm learning python in school and as a part of my current project I want to be able to make small "popups" on the screen. I've chosen to do this with wxpython but I've run into a problem. Right now I can't find a way to add a variable so I can print anything I want. I tried adding an extra variable both to the class and the **init** function but get an error for both. I'm not used to classes or how they work and I would really appreciate some help. Here is the code I am using:

```
import wx

class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        st = wx.StaticText(pnl, label = "Betting")
        font = st.GetFont()
        font.PointSize += 10
        font = font.Bold()
        st.SetFont(font)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(st, wx.SizerFlags().Border(wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, 25))
        pnl.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.makeMenuBar()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Welcome to wxPython!")

    def makeMenuBar(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        helloItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
        "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item")
        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)

        helpMenu = wx.Menu()
        aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&file")
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&help")

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHello, helloItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exitItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, aboutItem)

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnHello(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("Hello again from wxPython")

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("This is a wxPython Hello World Sample", "About Hello World 2", wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = number()
    app = wx.App()
    frm = HelloFrame(None, title='Betting predictions')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now I want to be able to input anything as a label into the `st = wx.StaticText(pnl, label = "Betting")`
Instead of just "Betting" and have it show whatever text I want but for the life of me I can't figure it out. This is a relatively small part of my project since I'm done and have some extra time but I would really like to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the label by calling the SetLabel member function on the static text. Now you are creating st as the local variable of the function **init**. You need to make it an instance variable like this:

```
class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.st = wx.StaticText(pnl, label = "Betting")
        [...]
        # then everywhere you use it, use self.st to access it like this:
        self.st.SetFont(font)
```

And if you want to change the label, for example after selecting a menu item:

```
def OnHello(self, event):
    wx.MessageBox("Hello again from wxPython")
    self.st.SetLabel("Changed label")
```

Or if you want to set the text when constructing the window, you can pass a parameter to the function (constructor):

```
class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, label_title, frame_title):
        super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(title=frame_title)

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.st = wx.StaticText(pnl, label = label_title)
        [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = "Some text"
    app = wx.App()
    frm = HelloFrame(None, t, frame_title='Betting predictions')
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm getting this error when trying to use the code:     frm = HelloFrame(None, info_string, title='Betting predictions')
    super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
TypeError: Frame(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: Oops! Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Petr Blahos's `instance` variable put into action.
Note that the `self.st.SetLabel()` is applied before the `MessageBox` or the label will not be updated until the message has been cancelled. `self.mycount` is also declared as an instance variable.

```
import wx

class HelloFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(HelloFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.st = wx.StaticText(pnl, label = "Betting")
        font = self.st.GetFont()
        font.PointSize += 10
        font = font.Bold()
        self.st.SetFont(font)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.st, wx.SizerFlags().Border(wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, 25))
        pnl.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.makeMenuBar()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("Welcome to wxPython!")
        self.mycount = 0
    # Show Frame and initially call OnHello (use None to compensate for a lack of event)
        self.Show()
        self.OnHello(None)

    def makeMenuBar(self):
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        helloItem = fileMenu.Append(-1, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H",
        "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item")
        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
        exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT)

        helpMenu = wx.Menu()
        aboutItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&file")
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&help")

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHello, helloItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exitItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, aboutItem)

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnHello(self, event):
        self.mycount += 1
        mystring = "Betting Display No: " + str(self.mycount)
        self.st.SetLabel(mystring)
        wx.MessageBox("Hello again from wxPython")

    def OnAbout(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox("This is a wxPython Hello World Sample", "About Hello World 2", wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frm = HelloFrame(None, title='Betting predictions')
    #frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Note: you can always create a `self.message` that can be set outside of the function and yet used within it. It's simplier than attempting a lambda function.

Comment: While this does work for changing the label when hitting the button in the window, I would like to be able to change it from the start. I have tried doing something like this:def OnHello(self, event, label):
        self.mycount += 1
        #mystring = "Betting Display No: " + str(self.mycount)
        self.st.SetLabel(label)
        wx.MessageBox("Hello again from wxPython")                                                              But then I have no idea where to call this function and input a label since I am never calling it, just frm = HelloFrame(None, title='Betting predictions')